# Screenshot window and save with environment variables

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have code to take a screenshot of a window, seen here:

```
SC.CaptureWindowToFile(Me.Handle, "c:\Program Files\image_" & Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

I want to be able to set an environment variable so that the images will be saved in a folder created by my installer, let's call it "Screenshots" and it's in the Documents folder. I assume I'll have to use something like:

```
 Dim fullPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

But I don't know how to combine these two together so it will save the screenshots into the folder in my documents. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, this should do it:

```
Dim myDocumentsPath as String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
Dim formattedDateString as String = Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")

Dim imagePath as String = String.Format("{0}\Screenshots\image_{1}.png", myDocumentsPath, formattedDateString)
SC.CaptureWindowToFile(Me.Handle, imagePath, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```